# Should [code-duplication] be merged with [dry]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[code-duplication](/questions/tagged/code-duplication) --> [dry](/questions/tagged/dry)?

---

Answer (score 10):

If you mean, as a synonym, I'd say **yes** — but the other way around: Make `dry` a synonym that converts to `code-duplication`. DRY is all the rage right now (and has been used more than the other), but if you don't know it, you're not going to guess it or immediately understand why it's shown up instead of what you typed; `code-duplication` and its current synonym `duplicate-code` are much more guessable and accessible. `dry` converting to `code-duplication` isn't going to confuse anyone, as they know what DRY is. Should probably throw `redundant-code` (9 uses) in there as well.

(Is DRY really limited to "code," though? Probably, if we take a sufficiently high-level view of what "code" is; these things *are* fuzzy.)

Comment: I'm inclined to agree. Let's see where the votes go with this answer.